# Runtime Error in UVa 594

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging, runtime-error, exit-code

I am trying to write a java code for [UVa 594 "One Little, Two Little, Three Little Endians"](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/5/594.html) .

Long story short: The problem is about taking inputs from the inputstream and converting from little endian to big endian and vice versa.
Here is my code:

```
  class Little_endians {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int x;
    String str;
    while((str=br.readLine())!=null){
        x=Integer.parseInt(str);
        System.out.println(x+" converts to "+Integer.reverseBytes(x));//converting to the other endian just requires to reverse the bytes
        }
 }
 }
```

It works on all the sample inputs given but on submission it showed:
**Your submission for the problem 594 - One Little, Two Little, Three Little Endians has failed with verdict Runtime error.This means that the execution of your program didn't finish properly. Remember to always terminate your code with the exit code 0.**

I think probably throws IOException takes care of the exit code 0.Could anyone help me find the cause for the runtime error.

Comment: Use `Scanner` to circumvent problems with newlines and other unexpected whitspace.

Comment: @NiklasB. Thank you. I'll check out Scanner. Could you tell me the problem in the above code ?

Comment: Probably whitespace-related

Comment: @NiklasB. on reaching EOF the program terminates returning 1 . The Debugger indicates the problem to be in the first statement of the while loop. Do you see anything incorrect in the code?

Comment: probably you try to parse an empty string.

Comment: @NiklasB. Yeah You're right .I thought empty string would be same as EOF . How do I enter EOF during the runtime?

Comment: I told you already, use `Scanner`. The problem is that you're trying to parse an empty string as an integer. You can just check whether the string is empty before you try that. But you'd should trim it first to remove trailing whitespace. You can also run into issues with CRLF line endings on Linux machines if the input files are badly formatted, which is often the case with these online judges. What's wrong with just using `Scanner`?

Comment: @NiklasB. here's what I've done:
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            int x;
            while(sc.hasNextInt()==true){
                    x=sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(x+" converts to "+Integer.reverseBytes(x));
              }
It still keeps reading empty strings.

Comment: I don't see a point where this would "read an empty string". In fact, you don't read strings at all.

Comment: I meant even if I dont enter anything, the loop does not end.

Comment: You need to close stdin for system.in to signal EOF. Just use the file redirection feature of your shell. Btw this is no longer a programming question but a basic question about how stdin works,  which is OS dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To submit a Java solution to UVa you need to always name your class **Main** and you file **Main.java** (people always hit upon this problem in UVa).Your code is correct.